# javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query with heroku PostgreSQL

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I am trying to use database in my app but keep getting this error. Its working fine on local machine when I uploaded it to heroku it keep giving this error. I spent my all day to get any solution but no success. So  if anyone can help me with this would be really helpful.

You can also find it on github.  : [**Github**](https://github.com/sanjay31321/spring-app)

**Error**

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query

type Exception report

message Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:965)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
root cause

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1389)
    org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1317)
    org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:255)
    org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.CriteriaQueryCompiler$3.getResultList(CriteriaQueryCompiler.java:253)
    com.spring.app.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.listUser(UserServiceImpl.java:25)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.listUser(Unknown Source)
    com.spring.app.HomeController.home(HomeController.java:34)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
root cause

org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92)
    org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2545)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
    org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:459)
    org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:365)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1268)
    org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
    org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:246)
    org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.CriteriaQueryCompiler$3.getResultList(CriteriaQueryCompiler.java:253)
    com.spring.app.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.listUser(UserServiceImpl.java:25)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.listUser(Unknown Source)
    com.spring.app.HomeController.home(HomeController.java:34)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column user0_.id does not exist
  Position: 8
    org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2103)
    org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1836)
    org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
    org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:512)
    org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388)
    org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:273)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1953)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:802)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2542)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
    org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:459)
    org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:365)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1268)
    org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
    org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:246)
    org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.CriteriaQueryCompiler$3.getResultList(CriteriaQueryCompiler.java:253)
    com.spring.app.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.listUser(UserServiceImpl.java:25)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.listUser(Unknown Source)
    com.spring.app.HomeController.home(HomeController.java:34)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.34 logs.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.34
```

**ServiceImpl Class**

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Transactional
    public List<User> listUser() {
        CriteriaQuery<User> c = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(User.class);
        c.from(User.class);
        return em.createQuery(c).getResultList();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void addUser(User user) {
        em.persist(user);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void deleteUser(int id) {
        User user = em.find(User.class, id);
        if (null != user) {
            em.remove(user);
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller class**

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    @Autowired private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, Map<String, Object> map) {
        logger.info("Welcome home! ");
        map.put("userList", userService.listUser());
        return "home";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result) {
        userService.addUser(user);
        return "redirect:/";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/delete/{id}")
    public String deleteUser(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {

        userService.deleteUser(id);
        return "redirect:/";
    }

}
```

**Spring Config Xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">


    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <context:annotation-config />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.app" />

    <!-- Database Connection -->
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>

    </bean>

    <beans profile="default">
        <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource"/>        
        <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
            <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
                <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
            </property>
            <property name="jpaProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </beans>

    <beans profile="prod">
        <bean class="java.net.URI" id="dbUrl">
            <constructor-arg value="#{systemEnvironment['DATABASE_URL']}"/>
        </bean>

        <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
            <property name="url" value="#{ 'jdbc:postgresql://' + @dbUrl.getHost() + ':' + @dbUrl.getPort() + @dbUrl.getPath() }"/>
            <property name="username" value="#{ @dbUrl.getUserInfo().split(':')[0] }"/>
            <property name="password" value="#{ @dbUrl.getUserInfo().split(':')[1] }"/>
        </bean>

        <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
            <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
                <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
            </property>
            <property name="jpaProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                    <!-- change this to 'verify' before running as a production app -->
                    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </beans>

</beans>
```

**Model Class**

```
@Entity 
public class User {

    @Id 
    @Column
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    //Setter and Getter
```

Comment: You don't have correct database schema in database your app is connecting to.

Comment: @Sanjay Kumar If you observe closely, the error log has: ERROR: column user0_.id does not exist. What is the column name you specified in the schema for table user? By default Column annotation will take property name i.e., id in your case.

Comment: @Prasad @ Niematojak I am using hibernate to access database and heroku provides a environment variable to connect to postgresSql database.  Thank you for replying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We also faced the same issue. We were having create in the xml and `@GeneratedValue` on the `id` column. The resolution is remove the `@GeneratedValue` annotation and put the value of the `id` manually, also the jpa takes long by default so give long value e.g `1l`.

To do the auto generation follow some another rule.

The issue around the JPA related auto generated Id is resolved as below:

Modify the `Person.java` model class to have the following annotations for the Id attribute:

```
@Id
@TableGenerator(name="TABLE_GEN",table="T_GENERATOR",pkColumnName="GEN_KEY",pkColumnValue="TEST",valueColumnName="GEN_VALUE",initialValue=1,allocationSize=1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE, generator="TABLE_GEN")
public Long Id;
```

This will create a table in the mysql schema called `T_GNERATOR` which will have the tracking of the next value for Id and JPA over hibernate knows how to retrieve this value. The assumtion is that the initial value for the Id is 1 and it is incremented by 1 on each new insertion into it as is obvious from the attributes of the annotation.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem on JavaDB/Derby. The solution was to use explicit table name != "user":
@Table(name = "my_user_table"). But it should be also fixed with a explicit schema because "user" is a system table

Comment: Thanks, this was the exact case at my side as well. I changed the name from "user" to "users" and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, solution was quite simple. The column that was registered in MySQL did not exist in a model. Therefore, I was getting the mentioned error message. Took me a bit of a time to troubleshoot.

Comment: here here. tore my god damn hair out, always worth a check.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you want to insert a field that does not exist in the MySql database.
For example the database field was deleted but it was not deleted from the model

Answer (score 0):

In my case I faced, javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement due to MySQL errors. One is the column specified twice and other is the incorrect column name.